# Reference "referencename" undefined for all my figures, same for citations

Tags: bibtex, cross-referencing

All my figure references and citations give the undefined warning, and the document will not compile. I have been very careful in checking for typos between `\label` and `\ref`. before I added the bibliography the figures worked fine, so it can't be a typo for them. I have tried running multiple times to make sure it can sort itself out but nothing.

I have

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin = 1.2in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\ref{figure1}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{"location".PNG}
\caption{caption}
\label{figure1}
\end{figure}

\cite(Straubetal2015)

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{Mybib}

\end{document}
```

and it wont work.
for the citations, all of them are formed by `\cite{...}` from a large `.bib` file. the `.bib` compiles with no errors, just a few *overfull \hbox*. A citation entry

```
 @article{
 Straubetal2015,
 Author = {Straub, J.M. and New, J. and Hamilton, C.D. and Lominska, C. and 
 Shnayder, Y. and Thomas, S.M.},
 Title = {Radiation-induced fibrosis: mechanisms and implications for 
 therapy},
 Journal = {Journal of Cancer Research and Clinical Oncology},
 Volume = {141},
 Pages = {1985-1994},
 Year = {2015},
 note = {https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4573901/}}
```

Comment: thats my bad in posting the question. It is done properly in latex

Comment: I don't remember why I'm using that, just that ive done it for all my latex docs. before I had references to them in the text, the images compiled properly

Comment: I actually removed all instances of `\cite` and `\ref`, replaced with manual numbering, so I don't have the original error messages right now. However, it was just a list of `Latex warning: Citation undefined...` or reference undefined. At the end was `LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.` The last line still appears even now with no references or citations in the text. Originally, every citation or reference was listed as undefined.